# Vue JS - Modifying object in for loop not updating live

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a loop of objects and I want to set flags on them so that I can change their "state" to "being edited" "newly created" etc and show the proper fields depending on the state. Here is my code:

```
<tr v-for="application in editForm.applicationsSelected" :key="application.id">
    <!-- Name -->
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;" v-if="!application.fresh">
        {{ application.name }}
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;" v-if="application.fresh">
        <select class="form-control" name="application_id" v-model="application.id">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select One</option>
            <option v-for="application in applications" v-bind:value="application.id">{{ application.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <!-- Appliction User ID -->
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"  v-if="!application.isEditing && !application.fresh">
        {{ application.pivot.application_user_id }}
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"  v-if="application.isEditing || application.fresh">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="application_user_id" v-model="application.pivot.application_user_id" />
    </td>

    <!-- Edit User Application -->
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;" v-if="application.isEditing">
        <a class="action-link" @click="updateUserApplication(application, editForm.id)">
            Save
        </a>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;" v-if="application.fresh">
        <a class="action-link" @click="attachUserApplication(application, editForm.id)">
            Save
        </a>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;" v-if="!isEditing && !application.fresh">
        <a class="action-link" @click="application.isEditing = true">
            Edit
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The important part is the edit button on the bottom. I want to set the objects "isEditing" flag to true and then show the input fields for that row. However, its simply not working. It will change the state of the application but not update the code till i close the modal and open it back up again (which forces a refresh of the application objects).

Also I plan on changing this to one property that takes on string "states" instead of changing multiple flags, however, for now I can't get the basic step down. Why is it that changing application.isEditing to true on click isn't switching which fields i see?

Comment: Is `isEditing` part of the `application` object before you set it? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Could you make a simple vue instance that reproduces your problem with minimal template, minimal css, sufficient data?

Comment: Can you provide the actual code? Like the js, along with a simple TLDR of what your input is, and what do you want as output along with where it errors? [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: actually I believe Bert hit the nail on the head. Its not originally part of it. I've seen that link though and using Vue.set() didn't seem to help at all :\

Comment: If the application objects are part of an AJAX response, you can iterate them after they are retrieved to add the property.

Comment: @Bert I changed the `@click` to a method call and inside that I used Vue.set and it worked beautifully. If you post an answer that delves into this I will mark it. If not I will post my new code with my best explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until version 3 of Vue arrives, you need to be careful about dynamically adding properties to objects. [Vue cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) when this happens and, as such, changes to the newly added property will not be reactively reflected in the DOM.

The primary ways of working around this are using [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) (or `this.$set` in a component) or adding the property *before* the object is added to Vue.

It appears OP solved the problem using Vue.set combined with a method event handler.

```
<a class="action-link" @click="onEdit(application)">
```

And in the code:

```
methods: {
  onEdit(application){
    this.$set(application, 'isEditing', true)
  }  
}
```